Populate dates based on number frequency and dates
I asked this question the other day: Populate dates based on frequency
It has been working really great!
I have tried to make a modification to this so it can accept monthly and yearly as an input. I have spent the last 2 days trying to modify the last soultion to no success ...



+
A
B
C
D
E
F




1
Start Date
End Date
Frequency
Cost
Category 
Company


2
02/02/2024
17/02/2024
14
545
Cow
First Farmers


3
02/02/2024
09/03/2024
Monthly
80
Donkey
Fighting First


4
03/02/2024
17/02/2024
7
23
Sheep
Outbacks


5
07/02/2024
17/02/2024
3
23
Pigs
Cowboys first


6
07/02/2024
10/09/2025
Yearly
90
Elephant
Circus Zoos



Making the output:



+
A
B
C
D
E




1
Date
Frequency
Cost
Category 
Company


2
02/02/2024
14
545
Cow
First Farmers


3
02/02/2024
Monthly
80
Donkey
Fighting First


4
03/02/2024
7
23
Sheep
Outbacks


5
07/02/2024
3
23
Pigs
Cowboys first


6
07/02/2024
Yearly
90
Elephant
Circus Zoos


7
10/02/2024
7
23
Sheep
Outbacks


8
10/02/2024
3
23
Pigs
Cowboys first


9
13/02/2024
3
23
Pigs
Cowboys first


10
16/02/2024
14
545
Cow
First Farmers


11
16/02/2024
3
23
Pigs
Cowboys first


12
17/02/2024
7
23
Sheep
Outbacks


13
02/03/2024
Monthly
80
Donkey
Fighting First


14
07/02/2025
Yearly
90
Elephant
Circus Zoos



=sort(let(Ξ,tocol(,1), reduce(Ξ,Input!A2:index(Input!A:A,match(,0/(Input!A:A<>""))),lambda(a,c,vstack(if(iserror(a&""),Ξ,a),let(x,offset(c,,1),y,offset(c,,2),Σ,quotient(x-c,y)+1,if(or(c="",x=""),Ξ, hstack(sequence(Σ,1,c,y),chooserows(offset(c,,2,,4),sequence(Σ,1,1,0))))))))),1,1,2,)
This works without yearly or monthly.
I made a EXAMPLE_SHEET so it may be easier to understand

Your expected output seems different here(Category: sheep) from whats in the test sheet?!

UPDATED FORMULA (do test out):
=sort(let(Ξ,tocol(,1), reduce(Ξ,Input!A2:index(Input!A:A,match(,0/(Input!A:A<>""))),lambda(a,c,vstack(if(iserror(a&""),Ξ,a),let(x,offset(c,,1),y,offset(c,,2),Σ,if(istext(y),datedif(c,x,switch(y,"Monthly","M","Yearly","Y")),quotient(x-c,y))+1,if(or(c="",x=""),Ξ,
 hstack(if(istext(y),index(edate(c,sequence(Σ,1,0,switch(y,"Monthly",1,"Yearly",12)))),sequence(Σ,1,c,y)),chooserows(offset(c,,2,,4),sequence(Σ,1,1,0))))))))),1,1,3,)



Thanks again mate (as you also solved the issue linked in this), exactly what I was hoping for!
